# Prove $\det(P+Q+R)=\det(P+Q)+\det(Q+R)+\det(R+P)-\det(P)-\det(Q)-\det(R)$

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $P,Q,R$ be three $2\times2$ matrices, then prove that 
$$\det(P+Q+R)=\det(P+Q)+\det(Q+R)+\det(R+P)-\det(P)-\det(Q)-\det(R).$$

**My Attempt**: I have no idea from where to start

Comment: Use the bilinearity of $\det$ in terms of the rows.

Comment: "An idea of where to start" ?  You can do it by "brute force" : take 12 indeterminate coefficients (4 for each matrix) and compute both sides... and compare. This is not a monstruous calculation.

Comment: More generally: If $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k$ are several $n\times n$-matrices with $k > n$, then $\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,k\right\}} \left(-1\right)^{\left|I\right|} \det\left(\sum\limits_{i \in I} A_i\right) = 0$.

Comment: @ darij grinberg Your comment is very interesting. Could you give a reference ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I am also interested in getting a reference for this general formula. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JeanMarie (and also Adren): I've proven my claim in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520370/determinant-of-a-sum-of-matrices/2527131#2527131 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(a_1 + a_2 + a_3) (d_1+d_2 + d_3)$ can be expanded as
$$(a_1 + a_2 + a_3) (d_1+d_2 + d_3) \\= (a_1 + a_2 )(d_1+d_2) + (a_2 + a_3)(d_2 + d_3) + (a_1 + a_3)(d_3+ d_1) - a_1 d_1 - a_2 d_2 -a_3 d_3.\tag 1$$
Similarly,
$$(b_1 + b_2 + b_3) (c_1+c_2 + c_3) \\= (b_1 + b_2 )(c_1+c_2) + (b_2 + b_3)(c_2 + c_3) + (b_1 + b_3)(c_3+ c_1) - b_1 c_1 - b_2 c_2 -b_3 c_3.\tag 2$$
Therefore, if $$P = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1\end{bmatrix},$$
$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2\end{bmatrix},$$
and
$$R = \begin{bmatrix}a_3 & b_3 \\ c_3 & d_3\end{bmatrix},$$
then using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can show that
$$\det(P+Q+R) = (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) (d_1+d_2 + d_3)-(b_1 + b_2 + b_3) (c_1+c_2 + c_3)\\=\det(P+Q) + \det(Q+R) + \det(R+P) - \det(P) -\det(Q) -\det(R).$$

Answer (score 8):

Notice for any $A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$, the characteristic polynomial has the form

$$\chi_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_2 - A)
= \lambda^2 - {\rm tr}(A)\lambda + \det(A)$$

Using Cayley Hamilton and taking trace again, we can express the determinant
in terms of the trace:

$$A^2 - {\rm tr}(A) A + \det(A) I_2 = 0
\quad\implies\quad \det(A) = \frac12\left({\rm tr}(A)^2 - {\rm tr}(A^2)\right)
$$
For any $A, B \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$, define a bracket between them by
$$\langle A, B \rangle \stackrel{def}{=} \det(A+B) - \det(A) - \det(B)$$
Using above expression of determinant, it is easy to verify:

$$\langle A, B \rangle = {\rm tr}(A){\rm tr}(B) - {\rm tr}(AB)$$

This means this sort of bracket is bilinear in terms of its arguments.
As a result, we obtain

$$\begin{align}\det(P+Q+R) 
= & \det(P+Q) + \det(R) + \langle P+Q, R \rangle\\
= & \det(P+Q) + \det(R) + \color{red}{\langle P, R \rangle} + \color{blue}{\langle Q, R \rangle}\\
= & \det(P+Q) + \det(R) 
   +\left(\color{red}{\det(P+R) - \det(P) - \det(R)}\right)\\
  & \quad + \left(\color{blue}{\det(Q+R) - \det(Q) - \det(R)}\right)\\
= & \det(P+Q) + \det(P+R) + \det(Q+R) - \det(P) - \det(Q) - \det(R)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$\det S$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $2$ in the entries of $S$, that is, a quadratic form. It is easier to prove the general fact: 
If $q\colon V \to W$ is a quadratic form then 
$$q(P+Q+R) - q(P+Q)- q(P+R) -q(Q+R) + q(P) + q(Q) + q(R)=0$$

The thing about quadratic forms, they come from bilinear forms ( symmetric too, if $char \ne 2$, but that is not important for this). So 
$$q(S) = b(S,S)$$ Substitute in the above, use bilinearity,  and observe that all of the terms cancel out.

$\bf{Added:}$ One should try to guess what is the equality that holds for cubic forms, or, more generally, for forms of degree $n$. It is also related to "polarization".

Answer (score 4):

If $\det(P) = p_{11}p_{22}-p_{21}p_{12}$, thrn

$$\det(P+Q+R) = (p_{11}+q_{11}+r_{11})(p_{22}+q_{22}+r_{22})-(p_{21}+q_{21}+r_{21})(p_{12}+q_{12}+r_{12})$$

You can start in that way.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Thank you for contributing to the website. In the future, please consider formatting your answer with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Regard the determinate as a mapping $\det: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is bilinear and a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ as two vectors
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}
\cong
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} \\
a_{2,1} 
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1,2} \\
 a_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
a_1
,a_2
\end{align}
where $a_1,a_2$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So we have $P \cong p_1,p_2$, $Q\cong q_1,q_2$ and $R \cong r_1, r_2$ and we start with
\begin{align}
\det(P+Q+R) = \det(p_1+q_1+r_1,p_2+q_2+r_2)
\end{align}
note that one property of bilinearity is $\det (a_1+b_1,a_2) = \det (a_1,a_2)+\det (b_1,a_2)$ and analogue in the second argument. Using this holds
\begin{align}
\det(p_1+q_1+r_1,p_2+q_2+r_2) &= \det(p_1+q_1,p_2+q_2+r_2) + \det(r_1,p_2+q_2+r_2)\\
&= \underbrace{\det(p_1+q_1,p_2+q_2)}_{\det(P+Q)} + \det(p_1+q_1,r_2) + \det(r_1,p_2+q_2+r_2)
\end{align}
Let us regard the remaining parts separately

- \begin{align}\begin{split}
  \det(p_1+q_1,r_2) &= \det(q_1+r_1,r_2) + \det(p_1-r_1,r_2)\\
  &= \underbrace{\det(q_1+r_1,q_2+r_2)}_{\det(Q+R)} + \det(q_1+r_1,-q_2) + \det(p_1-r_1,r_2)
  \end{split}\tag{1}
  \end{align}
- \begin{align}\begin{split}
  \det(r_1,p_2+q_2+r_2) &= \det(r_1,p_2+r_2) + \det(r_1,q_2) \\
  &= \underbrace{\det(p_1+r_1,p_2+r_2)}_{\det(P+R)} + \det(-p_1,p_2+r_2) + \det(r_1,q_2)
  \end{split}\tag{2}
  \end{align}

Note that from the bilinearity we have that $\det(a_1,-a_2) =  -\det(a_1,a_2)$
adding the remainders of $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yields
\begin{align}
\color{red}{\det(q_1+r_1,-q_2)} + \color{blue}{\det(p_1-r_1,r_2)}+\color{blue}{\det(-p_1,p_2+r_2)} + \color{red}{\det(r_1,q_2)}
\\= \color{red}{-\det(q_1,q_2)} + (\color{blue}{-\det(p_1,p_2) - \det(r_1,r_2)})
= -\det(P) - \det(Q)-\det(R)
\end{align}
Altogether this proves the desired identity.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [box product](https://youtu.be/bb0nYuRABwc) of the matrices, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\textstyle\bigwedge^2(P+Q+R)+\bigwedge^2P+\bigwedge^2Q+\bigwedge^2R&=\frac{1}{2}\bigl[\,(P+Q+R)\mathbin{\square}(P+Q+R)+P\mathbin{\square}P+Q\mathbin{\square}Q+R\mathbin{\square}R\,\bigr]\\
&=P\mathbin{\square}P+P\mathbin{\square}Q+P\mathbin{\square}R+Q\mathbin{\square}Q+Q\mathbin{\square}R+R\mathbin{\square}R\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigl[\,(P+Q)\mathbin{\square}(P+Q)+(P+R)\mathbin{\square}(P+R)+(Q+R)\mathbin{\square}(Q+R)\,\bigr]\\
&=\textstyle\bigwedge^2(P+Q)+\bigwedge^2(P+R)+\bigwedge^2(Q+R)
\end{align*}$$
The desired result now follows by taking the trace of both sides, since  $\mathrm{tr}(\,\bigwedge^2 M)=\det M$ for any $2\times 2$ matrix $M$.