# Determinant of a sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

I would like to know if the following formula is well known and get some references for it.

I don't know yet how to prove it (and I am working on it), but I am quite sure of its validity, after having performed a few symbolic computations with Maple.

Given $n$ square matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of size $m<n$ :

> $$\sum_{p=1}^n(-1)^p\sum_{1\leqslant i_1<\cdots<i_p\leqslant n}\det(A_{i_1}+\cdots+A_{i_p})=0$$

For example, if $A,B,C$ are three $2\times2$ matrices, then :

$$\det(A+B+C)-\left[\det(A+B)+\det(A+C)+\det(B+C)\right]+\det(A)+\det(B)+\det(C)=0$$

Comment: This is directly related to this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456054/)

Comment: @Somos: Thank you ! I will jump to it right now :)

Answer (score 5):

Let me outline two other proofs. Let me first rename your $m$ and $n$ as $n$
and $r$, since I find it confusing when $n$ is not the size of the square
matrices involved. So you are claiming the following:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>   and $r\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $n<r$. Let $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{r}$ be
>   $n\times n$-matrices over $\mathbb{K}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
> ^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\det\left(  \sum\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)  =0.
> \end{equation}

Notice that I've snuck in one more little change into your formula: I've added
the addend for $I=\varnothing$. This addend usually doesn't contribute much,
because $\det\left(  \sum\limits_{i\in\varnothing}A_{i}\right)  =\det\left(
0_{n\times n}\right)  $ is usually $0$... **unless** $n=0$, in which case it
contributes $\det\left(  0_{0\times0}\right)  =1$ (keep in mind that there is
only one $0\times0$-matrix and its determinant is $1$), and the whole equality
fails if this addend is missing.

A *first proof of Theorem 1* appears in (the solution to) Exercise 6.53 in [my
*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January
2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-10-01). (To obtain
Theorem 1 from this exercise, set $G=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  $.) The
main idea of this proof is that Theorem 1 holds not only for determinants, but
also for each of the $n!$ products that make up the determinant (assuming that
you define the determinant of an $n\times n$-matrix as a sum over the $n!$
permutations); this is proven by interchanging summation signs and exploiting
discrete "destructive interference" (i.e., the fact that if $G$ is a finite
set and $R$ is a subset of $G$, then $\sum\limits_{\substack{I\subseteq
G;\\R\subseteq I}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert I\right\vert }=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }R=G;\\
0, & \text{if }R\neq G
\end{cases}
$).

Let me now sketch a *second proof of Theorem 1*, which shows that it isn't
really about determinants. It is about finite differences, in a slightly more
general context than they are usually studied.

Let $M$ be any $\mathbb{K}$-module. The dual $\mathbb{K}$-module $M^{\vee
}=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}\left(  M,\mathbb{K}\right)  $ of
$M$ consists of all $\mathbb{K}$-linear maps $M\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$. Thus,
$M^{\vee}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-submodule of the $\mathbb{K}$-module
$\mathbb{K}^{M}$ of **all** maps $M\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$. The $\mathbb{K}
$-module $\mathbb{K}^{M}$ becomes a commutative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra (we just
define multiplication to be pointwise, i.e., the product $fg$ of two maps
$f,g:M\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ sends each $m\in M$ to $f\left(  m\right)
g\left(  m\right)  \in\mathbb{K}$).

For any $d\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $M^{\vee d}$ be the $\mathbb{K}$-linear span
of all elements of $\mathbb{K}^{M}$ of the form $f_{1}f_{2}\cdots f_{d}$ for
$f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{d}\in M^{\vee}$. (For $d=0$, the only such element is
the empty product $1$, so $M^{\vee0}$ consists of the constant maps
$M\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$. Notice also that $M^{\vee1}=M^{\vee}$.) The elements
of $M^{\vee d}$ are called *homogeneous polynomial functions of degree $d$ on
$M$*. The underlying idea is that if $M$ is a free $\mathbb{K}$-module with a
given basis, then the elements of $M^{\vee d}$ are the maps $M\rightarrow
\mathbb{K}$ that can be expressed as polynomials of the coordinate functions
with respect to this basis; but the $\mathbb{K}$-module $M^{\vee d}$ makes
perfect sense whether or not $M$ is free.

We also set $M^{\vee d}=0$ (the zero $\mathbb{K}$-submodule of $\mathbb{K}
^{M}$) for $d<0$.

For each $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define a $\mathbb{K}$-submodule
$M^{\vee \leq d}$ of $\mathbb{K}^M$ by
\begin{equation}
M^{\vee \leq d} = \sum\limits_{i \leq d} M^{\vee i} .
\end{equation}
The elements of $M^{\vee \leq d}$ are called *(inhomogeneous) polynomial
functions of degree $\leq d$ on $M$*.
The submodules $M^{\vee \leq d}$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
M^{\vee \leq d} M^{\vee \leq e} \subseteq M^{\vee \leq \left(d+e\right)}
\end{equation}
for any integers $d$ and $e$.

For any $x\in M$, we define the $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $S_{x}:\mathbb{K}
^{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}^{M}$ by setting
\begin{equation}
\left(  S_{x}f\right)  \left(  m\right)  =f\left(  m+x\right)  \qquad\text{for
each }m\in M\text{ and }f\in\mathbb{K}^{M}.
\end{equation}
This map $S_{x}$ is called a *shift operator*. It is an endomorphism of the
$\mathbb{K}$-algebra $\mathbb{K}^{M}$ and preserves all the $\mathbb{K}
$-submodules $M^{\vee \leq d}$ (for all $d\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Moreover, for any $x\in M$, we define the $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $\Delta
_{x}:\mathbb{K}^{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}^{M}$ by $\Delta_{x}
=\operatorname*{id}-S_{x}$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
\left(  \Delta_{x}f\right)  \left(  m\right)  =f\left(  m\right)  -f\left(
m+x\right)  \qquad\text{for each }m\in M\text{ and }f\in\mathbb{K}^{M}.
\end{equation}
This map $\Delta_{x}$ is called a *difference operator*. The following crucial
fact shows that it "decrements the degree" of a polynomial function, similarly
to how differentiation decrements the degree of a polynomial:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $x \in M$. Then,
>   $\Delta_{x}M^{\vee d}\subseteq M^{\vee \leq \left(  d-1\right)}$
>   for each $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

[Let me sketch a proof of Lemma 2:

Lemma 2 clearly holds for $d < 0$ (since $M^{\vee d} = 0$ if $d < 0$).
Hence, it remains to prove Lemma 2 for $d \geq 0$.
We shall prove this by induction on $d$.
The induction base is the case $d = 0$, which is easy to
check (indeed, each $f \in M^{\vee 0}$ is a constant map, and thus
satisfies $\Delta_x f = 0$; therefore,
$\Delta_{x}M^{\vee 0} = 0 \subseteq M^{\vee \leq \left(  0-1\right) }$).

For the induction step, we fix some nonnegative integer $e$, and assume
that Lemma 2 holds for $d = e$. We must then show that Lemma 2
holds for $d = e+1$.

We have assumed that Lemma 2 holds for $d = e$.
In other words, we have
$\Delta_{x}M^{\vee e}\subseteq M^{\vee \leq \left(  e-1\right)}$.

Our goal is to show that Lemma 2
holds for $d = e+1$. In other words, our goal is to show
that
$\Delta_{x}M^{\vee \left(e+1\right)}\subseteq M^{\vee \leq e}$.

But the $\mathbb{K}$-module $M^{\vee \left(e+1\right)}$ is
spanned by maps of the form $fg$ with $f\in M^{\vee e}$ and
$g\in M^{\vee}$ (since it is spanned by products of the
form $f_1 f_2 \cdots f_{e+1}$ with
$f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_{e+1} \in M^{\vee}$, but each such
product can be rewritten in the form $fg$
with $f = f_1 f_2 \cdots f_e \in M^{\vee e}$ and
$g = f_{e+1} \in M^{\vee}$).
Hence, it suffices to show that
$\Delta_x \left( fg \right) \in M^{\vee \leq e}$
for each $f\in M^{\vee e}$ and
$g\in M^{\vee}$.

Let us first notice that if $g \in M^{\vee}$ is arbitrary,
then $\Delta_x g$ is the constant map whose value is
$- g\left(x\right)$
(because each $m \in M$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\left(\Delta_x g\right) \left(m\right)
= g\left(m\right) - \underbrace{g\left(m+x\right)}_{\substack{=g\left(m\right) + g\left(x\right)\\ \text{(since }g \text{ is } \mathbb{K}\text{-linear)}}}
= g\left(m\right) - \left(g\left(m\right) + g\left(x\right)\right)
= - g\left(x\right)
\end{equation}
), and thus belongs to $M^{\vee 0}$.
In other words, $\Delta_x M^{\vee} \subseteq M^{\vee 0}$.

For each $f \in \mathbb{K}^M$ and $g \in \mathbb{K}^M$,
we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{x}\left(  fg\right)    & =\left(  \operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\right)
\left(  fg\right)  \qquad\left(  \text{since }\Delta_{x}=\operatorname*{id}
-S_{x}\right)  \\
& =fg-\underbrace{S_{x}\left(  fg\right)  }_{\substack{=\left(  S_{x}f\right)
\left(  S_{x}g\right)  \\\text{(since }S_{x}\text{ is an endomorphism}
\\\text{of the }\mathbb{K}\text{-algebra }\mathbb{K}^{M}\text{)}}}\\
& =fg-\left(  S_{x}f\right)  \left(  S_{x}g\right)  =\underbrace{\left(
f-S_{x}f\right)  }_{=\left(  \operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\right)  f}g+\left(
S_{x}f\right)  \underbrace{\left(  x-S_{x}g\right)  }_{=\left(
\operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\right)  g}\\
& =\left(  \underbrace{\left(  \operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\right)  }_{=\Delta
_{x}}f\right)  g+\left(  S_{x}f\right)  \left(  \underbrace{\left(
\operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\right)  }_{=\Delta_{x}}g\right)  \\
& =\left(  \Delta_{x}f\right)  g+\left( 
\underbrace{S_{x}}_{\substack{=\operatorname*{id}-\Delta_{x}\\
\text{(since }\Delta
_{x}=\operatorname*{id}-S_{x}\text{)}}}f\right)  \left(  \Delta_{x}g\right)
\\
& =\left(  \Delta_{x}f\right)  g+\underbrace{\left(  \left(
\operatorname*{id}-\Delta_{x}\right)  f\right)  }_{=f-\Delta_{x}f}\left(
\Delta_{x}g\right)  \\
& =\left(  \Delta_{x}f\right)  g+\left(  f-\Delta_{x}f\right)  \left(
\Delta_{x}g\right)  \\
& =\left(  \Delta_{x}f\right)  g+f\left(  \Delta_{x}g\right)  -\left(
\Delta_{x}f\right)  \left(  \Delta_{x}g\right)  .
\end{align*}
Hence, for each $f\in M^{\vee e}$ and $g\in M^{\vee}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{x}\left(  fg\right)    & =\left(  \Delta_{x}\underbrace{f}_{\in
M^{\vee e}}\right)  \underbrace{g}_{\in M^{\vee}}+\underbrace{f}_{\in M^{\vee
e}}\left(  \Delta_{x}\underbrace{g}_{\in M^{\vee}}\right)  -\left(  \Delta
_{x}\underbrace{f}_{\in M^{\vee e}}\right)
\left(  \Delta_{x}\underbrace{g}_{\in M^{\vee}}\right)  \\
& \in\underbrace{\left(  \Delta_{x}M^{\vee e}\right)  }_{\subseteq M^{\vee
\leq\left(  e-1\right)  }}M^{\vee}+M^{\vee e}\underbrace{\left(  \Delta
_{x}M^{\vee}\right)  }_{\subseteq M^{\vee0}}-\underbrace{\left(  \Delta
_{x}M^{\vee e}\right)  }_{\subseteq M^{\vee\leq\left(  e-1\right)  }
}\underbrace{\left(  \Delta_{x}M^{\vee}\right)  }_{\subseteq M^{\vee0}}\\
& \subseteq\underbrace{M^{\vee\leq\left(  e-1\right)  }M^{\vee}}_{\subseteq
M^{\vee\leq e}}+\underbrace{M^{\vee e}M^{\vee0}}_{\subseteq M^{\vee
e}\subseteq M^{\vee\leq e}}-\underbrace{M^{\vee\leq\left(  e-1\right)
}M^{\vee0}}_{\subseteq M^{\vee\leq\left(  e-1\right)  }\subseteq M^{\vee\leq
e}}\\
& \subseteq M^{\vee\leq e}+M^{\vee\leq e}-M^{\vee\leq e}\subseteq M^{\vee\leq
e}.
\end{align*}
This proves that $\Delta_{x}\left(  M^{\vee\left(  e+1\right)  }\right)
\subseteq M^{\vee\leq e}$, as we intended to prove.

Thus, the induction step is complete, and Lemma 2 is proven.]

The following fact follows by induction using Lemma 2:

> **Corollary 3.** Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{r}$ be $r$
>   elements of $M$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}M^{\vee d}\subseteq
> M^{\vee \leq \left(  d-r\right)  }
> \end{equation}
>   for each $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

And as a consequence of this, we obtain the following:

> **Corollary 4.** Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{r}$ be $r$
>   elements of $M$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}M^{\vee d}=0
> \end{equation}
>   for each $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $d<r$.

[In fact, Corollary 4 follows immediately from Corollary 3, because $d<r$
implies $M^{\vee \leq \left(  d-r\right)  }=0$.]

To make use of Corollary 4, we want a more-or-less explicit expression for how
$\Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}$ acts on maps in
$\mathbb{K}^{M}$. This is the following fact:

> **Proposition 5.** Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{r}$ be $r$
>   elements of $M$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \left(  \Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}f\right)  \left(
> m\right)  =\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
> ^{\left\vert I\right\vert }f\left(  m+\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}\right)
> \qquad\text{for each }m\in M\text{ and }f\in\mathbb{K}^{M}.
> \end{equation}

[Proposition 5 can be proven by induction over $r$, where the induction step
involves splitting the sum on the right hand side into the part with the $I$
that contain $r$ and the part with the $I$ that don't. But there is also a
slicker argument, which needs some preparation. The maps $S_{x}\in
\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{K}}\left(  \mathbb{K}^{M}\right)  $ for
different elements $x\in M$ commute; better yet, they satisfy the
multiplication rule $S_{x}S_{y}=S_{x+y}$ (as can be checked immediately).
Hence, by induction over $\left\vert I\right\vert $, we conclude that if $I$
is any finite set, and if $x_{i}$ is an element of $M$ for each $i\in I$, then
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{i\in I}S_{x_{i}}=S_{\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}}
\qquad \text{in the ring } \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{K}} \left(\mathbb{K}^M\right) .
\end{equation}
I shall refer to this fact as the *S-multiplication rule*.

Now, let us prove Proposition 5. Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{r}$ be $r$
elements of $M$. Recall the well-known formula
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  1-a_{i}\right)
=\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\prod\limits_{i\in I}a_{i},
\end{equation}
which holds whenever $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{r}$ are commuting elements of some
ring. Applying this formula to $a_{i}=S_{x_{i}}$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  \operatorname*{id}
-S_{x_{i}}\right)  =\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(
-1\right)  ^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\prod\limits_{i\in I}S_{x_{i}}
\end{equation}
(since $S_{x_{1}},S_{x_{2}},\ldots,S_{x_{r}}$ are commuting elements of the
ring $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{K}}\left(  \mathbb{K}^{M}\right)
$). Thus,
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}  & =\prod\limits_{i\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\underbrace{\Delta_{x_{i}}}
_{\substack{=\operatorname*{id}-S_{x_{i}}\\\text{(by the definition of }
\Delta_{x_{i}}\text{)}}}=\prod\limits_{i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(
\operatorname*{id}-S_{x_{i}}\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\underbrace{\prod\limits_{i\in I}S_{x_{i}}}
_{\substack{=S_{\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}}\\\text{(by the S-multiplication rule)}
}}=\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }S_{\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}}.
\end{align*}
Hence, for each $m\in M$ and $f\in\mathbb{K}^{M}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& \left(  \Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}}f\right)  \left(
m\right)  \\
& =\left(  \sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }S_{\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}}f\right)  \left(  m\right)
\\
& =\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\underbrace{\left(  S_{\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}}f\right)
\left(  m\right)  }_{\substack{=f\left(  m+\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}\right)
\\\text{(by the definition of the shift operators)}}}\\
& =\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }f\left(  m+\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}\right)  .
\end{align*}
Thus, Proposition 5 is proven.]

We can now combine Corollary 4 with Proposition 5 and obtain the following:

> **Corollary 6.** Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{r}$ be $r$ elements of $M$. Let
>   $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $d<r$. Let $f\in M^{\vee d}$ and $m\in M$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
> ^{\left\vert I\right\vert }f\left(  m+\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}\right)  =0.
> \end{equation}

[Indeed, Corollary 6 follows from the computation
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }f\left(  m+\sum\limits_{i\in I}x_{i}\right)  \\
& =\underbrace{\left(  \Delta_{x_{1}}\Delta_{x_{2}}\cdots\Delta_{x_{r}
}f\right)  }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(by Corollary 4, since } f \in M^{\vee d} \text{)}}}\left(  m\right)
\qquad\left(  \text{by Proposition 5}\right)  \\
& =0.
\end{align*}
]

Finally, let us prove Theorem 1. The matrix ring $\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ is a
$\mathbb{K}$-module. Let $M$ be this $\mathbb{K}$-module $\mathbb{K}^{n\times
n}$. For each $i,j\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $, we let $x_{i,j}$ be the
map $M\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ that sends each matrix $M$ to its $\left(
i,j\right)  $-th entry; this map $x_{i,j}$ is $\mathbb{K}$-linear and thus
belongs to $M^{\vee}$.

It is easy to see that the map $\det:\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}\rightarrow
\mathbb{K}$ (sending each $n\times n$-matrix to its determinant) is a
homogeneous polynomial function of degree $n$ on $M$; indeed, it can be
represented in the commutative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra $\mathbb{K}^M$ as
\begin{equation}
\det=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}x_{1,\sigma\left(
1\right)  }x_{2,\sigma\left(  2\right)  }\cdots x_{n,\sigma\left(  n\right)
},
\end{equation}
where $S_{n}$ is the $n$-th symmetric group, and where $\left(  -1\right)
^{\sigma}$ denotes the sign of a permutation $\sigma$. In other words,
$\det\in M^{\vee n}$. Hence, Corollary 6 (applied to $x_{i}=A_{i}$, $d=n$,
$f=\det$ and $m=0$) yields
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\det\left(  0+\sum\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)  =0.
\end{equation}
In other words,
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{I\subseteq\left\{  1,2,\ldots,r\right\}  }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert I\right\vert }\det\left(  \sum\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)  =0.
\end{equation}
This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 3):

Given integers $n > m > 0$, let $[n]$ be a short hand for the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{C}$, we have the identity

$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1 - e^{tx_k}) = \sum_{P \subset [n]} (-1)^{|P|} e^{t\sum_{k\in P} x_k}$$

Treat both sides as function of $t$. Expand against $t$, one notice on LHS, coefficients in front of $t^k$ vanishes whenever $k < n$. 
By comparing coefficients of $t^m$, we obtain:

$$ 0 = \sum_{P\subset [n]} (-1)^{|P|} \left(\sum_{k\in P} x_k\right)^m\tag{*1}$$

Notice RHS is a polynomial function in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with integer coefficients. Since it evaluates to $0$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, it is valid as a polynomial identity in $n$ indeterminates with integer coefficients. As a corollary, it is valid as an algebraic identity when $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are elements taken from any commutative algebra.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ spanned by
elements $\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_m$ and $\bar{\eta}_1,\ldots,\bar{\eta}_m$.

Let $\Lambda^{e}(V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^n \Lambda^{2k}(V)$ be the 'even' portion
of its exterior algebra. $\Lambda^{e}(V)$ itself is a commutative algebra.

For any $m \times m$ matrix $A$, let $\tilde{A} \in \Lambda^e(V)$ be the element defined by:

$$A = (a_{ij}) \quad\longrightarrow\quad \tilde{A} = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}\bar{\eta}_i \wedge \eta_j$$

Notice the $m$-fold power of $\tilde{A}$ satisfies an interesting identity:

$$\tilde{A}^m = \underbrace{\tilde{A} \wedge \cdots \wedge \tilde{A}}_{m \text{ times}} = \det(A) \omega
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\omega = m!\, \bar{\eta}_1 \wedge \eta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bar{\eta}_m \wedge \eta_m\tag{*2}$$

Given any $n$-tuple of matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in M_{m\times m}(\mathbb{C})$, if we substitute $x_k$ in $(*1)$ by $\tilde{A}_k$ and apply $(*2)$, we find

$$
\sum_{P\subset [n]} (-1)^{|P|} \left(\sum_{k\in P} \tilde{A}_k\right)^m
= \sum_{P\subset [n]} (-1)^{|P|} \det\left(\sum_{k\in P} A_k\right)\omega
= 0
$$
Extracting the coefficient in front of $\omega$, the desired identity follows:
$$\sum_{P\subset [n]} (-1)^{|P|} \det\left(\sum_{k\in P} A_k\right) = 0$$

Comment: A very beautiful result and very beautiful proof!

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this conclusion using the multilinear property of the determinant.

Given $n$ square matrices $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ of size $m<n$, proving
$$
\sum_{p=1}^n(-1)^p\sum_{1\le i_1 \le i_2 < \cdots<i_p\le n} \det (A_{i_1}+\cdots+A_{i_p})=0
$$
is equivalent to proving $\forall J=\{j_1,\cdots,j_m\}\subseteq I \subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, the coefficient of $\det (a_{j_1,1},\cdots,a_{j_m,m})$ is equal to $0$, where $a_{j_k,k}$ is the $k$-th column of $A_{j_k}$, $1\le k\le m$.

In fact, the coefficient is equal to
$$
\sum_{J\subseteq I\subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,n\}} (-1)^{|I|}=\sum_{|I|=|J|}^{n} (-1)^{|I|}\tbinom{n-|J|}{|I|-|J|}= (-1)^{|J|}(1-1)^{n-|J|}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is a form of degree $n$. Forms come from multilinear forms.

Consider $M$ an abelian group. For $a \in M$, denote by $a^{[n]}$ the element $a\otimes a \otimes \ldots \otimes a\in M^{\otimes n}$. Let now $a_i\in M$, $i \in I$, finitely many elements in $M$. Let's try to find 
$$\sum_{J\subset I}(-1)^{|I|-|J|}(\sum_{i \in J} a_i)^{[n]}$$

Consider a product $a_{i_1}\otimes \ldots \otimes a_{i_n}$. It appears in the above sum with the coefficient
$$\sum_{J\subset K \subset I}(-1)^{|I| - |J|}$$ where $J=\{i_1, \ldots, i_n \}$. This is $0$ for $J\ne I$ and $1$ for $J=I$. ( a Möbius function)

Therefore
$$\sum_{J\subset I}(-1)^{|I|-|J|}(\sum_{i \in J} a_i)^{[n]}=\sum_{\phi\colon \{1,\ldots n\}\to I,\phi\  \text{surjective}}a_{\phi(1)}\otimes \ldots a_{\phi(n)}$$

Particular cases:

1. $|I|>n$, we get $0$, the result desired.
2. $|I|=n$, we get $\sum_{\phi\colon \{1,\ldots n\}\to I,\phi\  \text{bijective}}a_{\phi(1)}\otimes \ldots a_{\phi(n)}$